# google map api autocomplete goes to wrong address

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete

I've typed in an address that I know exists into a google api autocomplete :

**642 Great Western Hwy Girraween NSW 2145**

[map example link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

-The autocomplete recognizes it, but...

The result I get is incorrect:

**642 Great Western Hwy, Faulconbridge NSW 2776, Australia**

For other addresses like this, 
is there any workaround for a fix?
I've investigated the  Autocomplete.getPlaces()
and can't seem to find a way around this.

-I even looked into AutocompleteServices objects (where the autocomplete gives the correct *prediction* - but is not within official *address_components*.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is ongoing issue on Google side and it was reported in Google issue tracker several days ago. You can find it here:

[Locality/postal_code in Place Details does not align with Place Autocomplete description.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111160335)

Google is looking into it and hopefully they will find solution soon. I would suggest starring the bug to add your vote and subscribe to notifications from Google.

In the meantime the unique workaround I can think of is using a formatted string from autocomplete prediction and resolve it using Geocoding API service instead of getting place details using a place ID.

For example, you execute autocomplete request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=642%20Great%20Western%20Hwy%20Girraween%20NSW%202145&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

It returns the following values in the response JSON:

"description":"642 Great Western Hwy, Girraween NSW 2145, Australia"
"place_id":"EjQ2NDIgR3JlYXQgV2VzdGVybiBId3ksIEdpcnJhd2VlbiBOU1cgMjE0NSwgQXVzdHJhbGlhIjESLwoUChIJ1Ww4O998EmsRmSCZE6S6OVMQggUqFAoSCdtIcBNscBJrESbra3OWkCBW"

If you use place ID to get details it resolves to wrong address

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=EjQ2NDIgR3JlYXQgV2VzdGVybiBId3ksIEdpcnJhd2VlbiBOU1cgMjE0NSwgQXVzdHJhbGlhIjESLwoUChIJ1Ww4O998EmsRmSCZE6S6OVMQggUqFAoSCdtIcBNscBJrESbra3OWkCBW&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

However, if you use geocoding with text from description you get correct address:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=642%20Great%20Western%20Hwy%20Girraween%20NSW%202145&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

You can also see this in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D642%2520Great%2520Western%2520Hwy%2520Girraween%2520NSW%25202145

I hope this helps!